# Replace String with EditText View for Fill in the Blank Quiz

Tags: android, view

I'm working on a fill in the blank quiz that turns a paragraph from Wikipedia into a quiz. I would like to replace keywords from the paragraph with `EditText` views, but I don't think this is possible with regex. I tried replacing the links (eg keywords) from the paragraph with new Views, but it only accepts strings as second parameter.

`String quiz = quiz.replaceAll("<a href=.*?>.*?</a>", new EditText(mContext)); //DOESN'T WORK`

Is there an alternative way  to replace strings with views? I am putting the string `quiz` inside a `TextView` and was hoping there would be a way to programmatically put `EditTexts` in the right places.

Comment: i think by using regex you should replace the keyword with '_____' and then to the very below line with fill in the blanks there should be a edit text where user can input answer like

\n
this is line and this is fill in the __________ \n
(here is the edit text  where user can put the answer)

Comment: so something like this? `quiz = quiz.replaceAll("<a href=.*?>.*?</a>", "         \n"); ` Do you know how to add EditText after each blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically we need to add TextView and EditTexts to parent layout. 
Parent layout is your wish like LinearLayout with Orientation as Horizontal.

when you want to replace the string with Edittext, first store the text before that "replace string" and set that text to TextView and add the TextView to parent and then add EditText. And reset the local storing string and assign the next string by continuing to store the string till next replaced position.
Ex: "World best batsman is X". and I want to replace "X" with EditText.
First, I store the text before "X" in the string and set that text to TextView and finally add TextView to Parent and then add Edittext in place of "X".X is the delimiter in this case. you can use anything.
[image]

```
    LinearLayout parentLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    parentLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    editText.setMinEms(5);

    parentLayout.addView(textView);
    parentLayout.addView(editText);

    int replacedIndex = inputString.indexOf('X');
    String inputText = inputString.substring(0, replacedIndex);
    textView.setText(inputText);
```

Comment: `LinearLayout` won't work here because it will add the `TextView` and `EditText` on different lines, they will not be next to each other.

Comment: By making the LinearLayout with Orientation as Horizontal we can get that behavior. If you want TextView and EditText on different lines then we need to set Orientation as Vertical

Comment: Nope, it won't work. If you set the orientation horizontal, the `TextView` will take the entire width of the screen and hide the `EditText`.

Comment: If we set the android:layout_width="match_parent" then it will take like this. in this case we need to set android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: I was talking about the `wrap_content` and the same issue will appear. The point is that Android doesn't have a layout where you can add views one after another (or at least I don't know about one). If you can find a layout like this, then the entire problem is fixed.

Comment: thank you for the code. it helped me get closer to a solution. I guess I'll have to live with separate lines

Comment: If you want to show on separate lines then please change parentLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); to parentLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);. So, each TextView and EditText will add in vertical direction. And if you have more views like this then please use ScrollView as well.